# Utilizar Union Select Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Estou tentando utilizar um Union select, em um entity framework, porém não estou conseguindo juntar as informações, segue como estou tentando fazer:

```
 var un = _context.CaixaMovimentos.Select(c => new
        {
            c.Data, c.Hora, Histórico = c.Historico, c.Forma

        }).ToList()
        .Union(_context.ContasReceber.Select(r => new
        {
            r.DataPagamento, Hora = r.DataPagamento, r.Observacao, r.FormaPagamento
        }).ToList()).Union(_context.ContasApagar.Select(p => new {
            p.DataPagamento, Hora = p.DataPagamento, p.Obs, p.FormaPagamento
        }).ToList());
```

Só que ele me retorna erro. Como posso fazer ?

Consegui resolver, fazendo desta forma:

```
 var un = _context.CaixaMovimentos.Select(c => new
        {
            Data = c.Data,
            Hora = c.Hora,
            Histórico = c.Historico,
            Valor = c.Valor,
            Forma = c.Forma

        }).ToList()
        .Union(_context.ContasReceber.Select(r => new
        {
            Data = r.DataPagamento,
            Hora = r.DataPagamento,
            Histórico = r.Observacao,
            Valor = r.ValorPago,
            Forma = r.FormaPagamento
        }).ToList()).Union(_context.ContasApagar.Select(p => new
        {
            Data = p.DataPagamento,
            Hora = p.DataPagamento,
            Histórico = p.Obs,
            Valor = p.ValorPago,
            Forma = p.FormaPagamento
        }).ToList());
```

Porém não sei como relacionar estes campos, com a minha tabela.

Comment: Olá, Mariana. Qual erro? Adicione o erro que está tendo, editando sua pergunta.

Comment: Consegui resolver, obrigado @Dherik, eu não estava entendendo como funcionava, você sabe me dizer como que eu consigo jogar na tabela os dados ?